# C# or other .NET equivalents of core python modules for IronPython?

Tags: c#, .net, python, ironpython

I would like to compile and distribute (on .net) some python programs that work well with IronPython, but I am new to .net and am getting errors related to particular python modules.  There is a utility for compiling to low level .net and it works well, but I get errors when dealing with common libraries; code that runs in the interpreter does not necessarily compile.  For example, the below takes advantage of the basic modules `shutil`, `getpass`, and `os`.  `getpass.getuser()` returns a username as a string.  `shutil` provides, among other things, a copy function (although that one I can rewrite in pure python and get to compile), and `os` is used here for getting folder info, making dirs and unlinking files.  How might I adapt stuff along the following lines, in whole or any part, to use only libraries native to .net?  If anyone has used IronPython as a bridge from python to learning .net any related tips are appreciated.

```
import shutil
import os
import getpass

uname = getpass.getuser()

folders = ["/users/"+uname+"/location", "/users/"+uname+"/other_location"]

for folder in folders:
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            file_name = os.path.join(root, file)
            time_stamp = os.stat(file_name).st_mtime
            time_dict[time_stamp] = file_name
            working_list.append(time_stamp)


def sync_up():
    for item in working_list:
        if item not in update_list:
            os.remove(item)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(item, some_other_folder)

def cp_function(target=some_folder):
    if os.path.exists(target):
        sync_up()
    else:
        try:
            os.mkdir(target)
            sync_up()
        except:
            print """error connecting
            """
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os` (and `shutil` ) replacements in .NET are in the [`System.IO` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx).

> The System.IO namespace contains types that allow reading and writing to files and data streams, and types that provide basic file and directory support.

For most of your file file operations, try the methods of the [`System.IO.File` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_members.aspx).
Directory information is available via the [`System.IO.Directory` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_members.aspx).

I'm not aware of a native `os.walk` alternative, try using the `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` methods to construct your own directory walker. There is an example *RecursiveFileProcessor* in the [`Directory.GetDirectories(String)` doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx).

A simple way to retrieve the user name of the person who is currently logged on, could be the [`System.Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) property.

A simple interactive IronPython example:

```
>>> import clr
>>> from System import Environment
>>> Environment.UserName
'gimel'
>>> from System import IO
>>> IO.Directory.GetCreationTimeUtc('c:/')
<System.DateTime object at 0x000000000000002B [02/07/2006 12:53:25]>
>>> IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc('c:/')
<System.DateTime object at 0x000000000000002C [09/11/2009 08:15:32]>
>>> IO.Directory.GetDirectories('C:/').Count
24
>>> help(IO.File.Copy)
Help on built-in function Copy:

Copy(...)
    Copy(str sourceFileName, str destFileName, bool overwrite)

        Copies an existing file to a new file.
         Overwriting a file of the same name is allowed.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `os` module you can use the `nt` module which provides some of the same functions as `os` including `stat`, `remove`, and `mkdir`.  (It also includes others like `environ`, `getcwd`, `chdir`,and `popen`.)

For example:

```
» import nt
» nt.getcwd()
'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE'
```

However, the implementation is incomplete so, unfortunately, it does not have `path` or `walk`.  For those, you might need to use .NET's `System.IO` as [gimel suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699856/c-or-other-net-equivalents-of-core-python-modules-for-ironpython/1700001#1700001).